# How to replace only last specific character (dot) with tab in a string using SED? String is an IP address

Tags: sed

I would like to replace only last character (dot) in a string (IP address) with a tab. Suppose, if I have 10.25.16.19.4, I would want output as 10.25.16.19  4 (As after the last dot, what we have is the port).
If we have localhost.42916, expected output is as:- localhost  42916

Catch is:- Only last dot should be replaced with tab and remaining should be left as such.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use this substitution:

```
s@\(.*\)\.@\1\t@
```

That is, capture everything up to the last dot, replace it with itself plus a tab.

Comment: Hi, I am using this command netstat | grep -e tcp -e udp | sed ':l ; s/\(.*\)\.\(.*\)/\1 \2/g ; tl' and I expect that in the output, columns 4th and 5th (local and foreign address) are split with the port (the part after the last dot). However, this doesnt work and gives an error:- sed: The label :l ; s/\(.*\)\.\(.*\)/\1 \2/g ; tl is greater than eight characters. Any idea whats wrong here? Is there any other to achieve this?

Comment: @HappySingh: first, netstat prints like `address:port` not `address.port`.  Second, you need to put `\` before `(` and `)` in your `sed` command.

Comment: Hey John, unfortunately I am on HP-UX and not on Linux. So, it prints address.port   On linux, my sed worked fine and I easily got that working. Now, I need that to work on HP-UX i.e. sed on netstat should split the port from ip address for both local and foreign address.

Comment: Well like I tried to say but messed up the formatting, you must escape your parens, so: `sed ':l ; s/\(.*\)\.\(.*\)/\1 \2/g ; tl'`

Answer (score 1):

Use the end of line anchor $:

```
sed -e 's/\.\([0-9]+\)$/\t\1/'
```

"\1" is group 1, which is the captured port.

Comment: Tried using this, I get an error:- $ sed -e 's/\.([0-9]+)$/\t\1/' test.out
sed: Function s/\.([0-9]+)$/\t\1/ cannot be parsed.

Comment: Hi, I am using this command netstat | grep -e tcp -e udp | sed ':l ; s/\(.*\)\.\(.*\)/\1 \2/g ; tl' and I expect that in the output, columns 4th and 5th (local and foreign address) are split with the port (the part after the last dot). However, this doesnt work and gives an error:- sed: The label :l ; s/\(.*\)\.\(.*\)/\1 \2/g ; tl is greater than eight characters. Any idea whats wrong here? Is there any other to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/\([a-zA-Z][^[:space:]]*\)\.\([0-9]\{1,3\}\)/\1   \2/g;s/\(\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}\)\.\([0-9]\{1,3\}\)/\1 \3/g'
```

if there is something else than IP5 on the line, you could use this. It's not bullet proof (IP6, ...) but should work in 99% of all case. Posix versin so `--posix` on GNU sed

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this but this didnt seperated the last dot with the tab. Am I doing something wrong?               $ sed 's/\(\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}\)\.\([0-9]\{1,3\}\)/\1 \2/g' test.out
localhost.78
tal.crack.9876

Comment: please give some line of sample so i can test with your data. I test on your text (also a small bug already edited, this is `\3` and not `\2` at the end)

Comment: Hi, I am using this command netstat | grep -e tcp -e udp | sed ':l ; s/\(.*\)\.\(.*\)/\1 \2/g ; tl' and I expect that in the output, columns 4th and 5th (local and foreign address) are split with the port (the part after the last dot). However, this doesnt work and gives an error:- sed: The label :l ; s/\(.*\)\.\(.*\)/\1 \2/g ; tl is greater than eight characters. Any idea whats wrong here? Is there any other to achieve this?

Comment: remove the space after the :l and if not enough replace the `;` by a new line. In a posix version, a label is only followed by a new line where GNU sed allow a `;`

Comment: I tried this but now this error:- $ netstat | grep -e tcp -e udp | sed ':l
> s/(.*)\.(.*)/\1 \2/g
> tl'
sed: Function s/(.*)\.(.*)/\1 \2/g cannot be parsed.

Comment: > is the next line basically

Comment: escape your `()` with `\ ` (without space), if not it is used as litteral character and not as a group so `\1` and `\2` are not define

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
sed 's/\(.*\)\.\(.*\)/\1\t\2/' file name
```

Input:

```
localhost.78 
tal.crack.9876
```

Output:

```
localhost   78 
tal.crack   9876
```

Comment: I tried this but this didnt worked. I created a file "test.out" with 2 entries in it:- localhost.78 and tal.crack.9876 and I would expect the output as localhost   78 and tal.crack    9876. But when I run the above sed with my file, I get output like:- localhostt78
tal.crackt9876
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Input is same line or seperate line??

Comment: For me, it didnt. I am on HP-UX. Would that affect the parsing?

Comment: In that instead of `\t` you can use the space. I think \t is not working. You can use the space.

Comment: Thanks mate. This worked. I would really appreciate if you can just explain this command for my understanding - whenever you find a minute to do so. Thanks.

Comment: @HappySingh `\(.*\)\.` It is for getting teh all charcters up to the . comes. so in thiswe are mentioning the . is must. After that dot there wil be any charcter so for that second one `\(.*\).` In substitution instead of '.' place the space or tab.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. However, I am stuck with another issue here. When I apply sed to the output from netstat, I basically want to split IP address from columns 4th and 5th (local and foreign address), which doesn't happen when I use this sed. Command used is:- netstat | grep -e tcp -e udp sed 's/\(.*\)\.\(.*\)/\1\ \2/'

Comment: It splits some of the IP address from column 4 i.e. local address and then some from column 5 i.e. foreign address. I need the IP address split from port (occurs after last dot) for both these address. I am on HP-UX. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: @HappySingh `netstat | grep -e tcp -e udp | sed  ':l s/\(.*\)\.\(.*\)/\1 \2/g ;tl '` Use this one.

Comment: Thanks for the quick revert, I tried this but get an error message:- $  netstat | grep -e tcp -e udp | sed ':l s/\(.*\)\.\(.*\)/\1 \2/g ;tl '
sed: The label :l s/\(.*\)\.\(.*\)/\1 \2/g ;tl  is greater than eight characters.

Comment: You can try place the semicolon after that label `:l ;`

Comment: Tried placing that semicolon, still the same error :(

Comment: Are you escaping the brackets are not?

Comment: I actually tried the sed as it as.. As I posted in my comment above. Just included the semicolon like :1;     Is there something else which I need to take care of? I havent used sed much with regex.

Comment: You have to place like this. `:l ; s/\(.*\)\.\(.*\)/\1 \2/g ; tl` Here it is a l not one.

Comment: Hi, tried exactly like you mentioned but still the same error:- $ netstat | grep -e tcp -e udp | sed ':l ; s/\(.*\)\.\(.*\)/\1 \2/g ; t|'
sed: The label :l ; s/\(.*\)\.\(.*\)/\1 \2/g ; t| is greater than eight characters.

Comment: Like you said, in the beginning of sed, its alphabet l and at the end, its a | (pipe) and not numeric one.

Comment: Am I still missing something?

Comment: At the end is also a alphabet l. Not a pipe.

Comment: I tried with the alphabet l as well. No luck and it still gives the  greater than 8 characters error. Not sure whats wrong. Is the same command working with your netstat? I am literally stuck here :(

Comment: Are you also using the HP-UX? I am trying exactly the same way as you mentioned but I am getting the same error again and again. Is there anything else you would think of - which could be wrong?

Comment: No I am using Ubuntu. And I didn't get the idea why you are getting the error message